# Join rows in pandas, shift by one and create new data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame as follows

```
I/P
date,low,high,close
d1,l1,h1,c1
d2,l2,h2,c2
d3,l3,h3,c3
d4,l4,h4,c4
d5,l5,h5,c5
d6,l6,h5,c5
d7,l7,h7,c7

O/P
d1,l1,h1,c1,d2,l2,h2,c2,d3,l3,h3,c3
d2,l2,h2,c2,d3,l3,h3,c3,d4,l5,h4,c4
d3,l3,h3,c3,d4,l5,h4,c4,d5,l5,h5,c5
d4,l5,h4,c4,d5,l5,h5,c5,d6,l6,h6,c6
....
```

Basically join all rows, split into subarrays of 3 size each staring at each index, and create the op data frame.

Following code works. Buts its too verbose and slow. Does pandas have something inbuilt for this?

```
def flatten(df):
    candles = []
    i = 0
    while i < len(df):
        candles.append(df.iloc[i])
        i= i+1
    
    return candles
    
def slide_and_expand(candles, k):
    return [candles[i:i+k] for i in range(len(candles) - k + 1)]

def candle_to_dict(col_name_prefix, candle_series):
    candle_dict = {}
    for index, val in candle_series.iteritems():
        col_name = col_name_prefix+index
        candle_dict[col_name] = val
    return candle_dict 

def candle_group_to_feature_vector(candle_group):
    feature_vector_dict = {}
    i = 0
    for candle in candle_group:
        col_name_prefix = f"c{i}_"
        candle_dict = candle_to_dict(col_name_prefix, candle)
        feature_vector_dict.update(candle_dict)
        i= i+1
    return feature_vector_dict   
  
def candle_groups_to_feature_vectors(candle_groups):
    feature_vectors = []
    for candle_group in candle_groups:
        feature_vector = candle_group_to_feature_vector(candle_group)
        feature_vectors.append(feature_vector)
    return feature_vectors
    
fv_len = 3
candles = flatten(data)
candle_groups = slide_and_expand(candles,fv_len)
feature_vectors = candle_groups_to_feature_vectors(candle_groups)
data_fv = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(feature_vectors, orient='columns')
data_fv
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
n = len(df.index) # number of rows in original dataframe 'df'
df_0 = df.loc[0:n-3]
df_1 = df.loc[1:n-2]
df_2 = df.loc[2:n-1]
df_final = pandas.concat([df_0, df_1, df_2], axis = 1)
```

Comment: I have thousands of rows in my df. Also i mentioned 3 as sample, actual is 100 for each subarray

Comment: @user93796 In that case you could simply use a loop. How many thousands of rows are there? If it's in the order of tens of thousands, and subarrays of size 100, then the execution time should not be more than a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can save a few steps using Pandas [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) function using the windows size as the desired subarray length (`window=SUBARR_SZ`). Then, join each column with a `,`, transform the result to a Series to be able to apply a `join` again, but now using each row in the Series (which contains the specific amount of subarrays).

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')

SUBARR_SZ = 3 # subarray size

df_list = []
for w in df.rolling(window=SUBARR_SZ):
    if len(w) == SUBARR_SZ:
        s = w.apply(','.join, axis=1).apply(pd.Series).apply(','.join)
        df_list.append(s)

dff = pd.concat(df_list).reset_index(drop=True)
print(dff)
```

Output from *dff*

```py
0    d1,l1,h1,c1,d2,l2,h2,c2,d3,l3,h3,c3
1    d2,l2,h2,c2,d3,l3,h3,c3,d4,l4,h4,c4
2    d3,l3,h3,c3,d4,l4,h4,c4,d5,l5,h5,c5
3    d4,l4,h4,c4,d5,l5,h5,c5,d6,l6,h6,c6
4    d5,l5,h5,c5,d6,l6,h6,c6,d7,l7,h7,c7
dtype: object
```